# Create two models from one view django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

That may seem obvious, but I cannot figure it out for a while. I have three models: `Project`, `Question_Text`, and `Question`. `Question` has *`ForeignKey`* to the `Project` and to the `Question_Text`. I can create and save `Project`, but when I'm creating `Question_Text`, I should also create a `Question` in my understanding, from one view. I tried to use `Question.objects.create()`, however, my dances around this seem *fatal*. I get the below error:

```
table project_question has no column named question_text_id
```

From DB point of view it's like this:

```
"question_text_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "project_question_text" ("id")
```

My *models*:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    audience_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    audience_ready = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("Date Created")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Question_Text(models.Model):
    text_en = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)


class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    question_text = models.ForeignKey(Question_Text)
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.question_text
```

My *view*:

```py
def add_question(request, project_id):
    a = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        f = QuestionTextForm(request.POST)
        if f.is_valid():
            c = f.save(commit=False)
            #          c.pub_date = timezone.now()
            q = Question.objects.create()
            q.question_text = c
            q.project = a
            q.save()
            c.save()

            messages.success(request, "Your question was added")

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/projects/get/%s' % project_id)

    else:
        f = QuestionTextForm(request.POST) #Add request params to initialization


    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    #    args['question'] = q
    args['project'] = a
    args['form'] = f

    return render_to_response('project/add_question.html', args)
```

And my *form*:

```py
class QuestionTextForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question_Text
        fields = ('text_en',)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving `q` before `c`. But as `q` has field (foreignkey) for `c`, `c` needs to be saved first. Django internally refers id of `c` to update the tables and rows appropriately.

So change your code to

```
    c = f.save(commit=False)
    #          c.pub_date = timezone.now()
    c.save() #save c

    #prepare object
    q = Question()
    q.question_text = c
    q.project = a
    q.user = request.user
    q.save()
```

Comment: If I do so, I get project_question_text.question_id may not be NULL, do you understand why? I run syncdb, I used schemamigration, migrate using south.. That is the point I started from.

Comment: @user3310881, see updated answer. `Question.objects.create()` will not work as that objects needs some non-null fields.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, it gives the same project_question_text.question_id may not be NULL at c.save(), if I understand correctly.

Comment: If I use debugger it gives me:(Pdb) print c.id
None, (Pdb) print c.text_en
'MyQuestion'

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! I deleted a database to start from scratch and it seems to work. As I mentioned, I used syncdb and migrate, but.. I don't know.

Comment: One more little question..Do you know how can I display this Question_Text?  {% for c in project.question_set.all %}
<p>{{c.question_text}}
<a href="/projects/delete_question/{{c.id}}">Delete question</a>
</p>
{% endfor %}   This displays an object..

Comment: That was <p> {{q.question_text.text_en}}, simple!